# Is it possible to perform save point and rollback operations on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB, is it possible to create a save point and perform rollback in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB supports [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) but I think that you are talking about the backup/restore mechanisms. In this case, MongoDB does not offer any special functionality, only classical [dump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)/[restore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/).

But the [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) (MongoDB SaaS) can offer the [continuous backups](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/backup/continuous-backups) functionality (snapshots and point-in-time).

The other solution would be to implement the content versioning functionality in your application or via some sort of middleware/service.

Comment: I have a small doubt like  i will update some columns in the collection but after some time it's possible to go to the previous state before update i don't think its similar to backup/restore operations.

Comment: Yeah... MongoDB does not offer that functionality by itself. It can be implemented as the content versioning functionality by your application or some sort of middleware.